# Extra package installation in boot2docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, installation, boot2docker

I am running a virtual machine using boot2docker. I have to install extra packages (e.g Python library). I read I should use the command `tce-load` command for the installation, but when I enter this command I get already the error: `tce-load: command not found`.
Any idea about how this can be fixed?

Thank you very much for your help!